# Get Pandas Dataframe Column names from Numpy Array

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe imported from excel:

```
>>df

    Name Emp ID  Total Salary     A      B     C     D      E
0   Mike   A001         25000  5000  15000  3000     0   2000
1   John   A002         23000  5000  10000  3000  3000   2000
2    Bob   A003         21000  5000  15000     0  1000      0
3   Rose   A004         20000  5000  10000  2000  1000  20000
4  James   A005         10000  5000      0  3000     0   2000
```

Now I have calculated the sum of subset of Total Salary using the following code:

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('tmp/test.xlsx')
val = df.drop(['Name','Emp ID','Total Salary'],1)
test = np.array(val)

num = df['Total Salary'][0]
array = test[0]

def subsetsum(array,num):
    if num == 0 or num < 1:
        return None
    elif len(array) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        if np.isclose(array[0],num):
            return [array[0]]
    else:
        with_v = subsetsum(array[1:],(num - array[0])) 
        if with_v:
            return [array[0]] + with_v
        else:
            return subsetsum(array[1:],num)

print('\nValues : ',array)
print('\nTotal Salary : ',num)
print('\nValues of Salary : ',subsetsum(array,num))
```

**Output:**

```
Values :  [ 5000 15000  3000     0  2000]

Total Salary :  25000

Values of Salary :  [5000, 15000, 3000, 0, 2000]
```

Now I need a way to link the values of salary present in the array to the column names present in data frame.

So my output that I would like would be:

**Output Required:**

```
Values :  [ 5000 15000  3000     0  2000]

Total Salary :  25000

Values of Salary :  A - 5000 B - 15000 C - 3000 E - 2000
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest rewriting your `subsetsum` function to return the *indices* of the chosen elements, rather than the elements themselves (or perhaps it could return both, if that works out to be better for you). For example,

```
subsetsum([5000, 15000, 3000, 0, 2000], 25000)
```

would return `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, or possibly `[0, 1, 2, 4]`. Then you can use these indices to access the corresponding column labels as well as the elements.

Comment: I have tried around but have failed, could you please guide me how to do it. Please..it would be a great help!!

Comment: @cgmaster What have you tried, and why did it fail?

Comment: I am unable to extract index values from the function. When I try the to extract the values individually so that I can get the index, it throws me None
[2000]
[3000, 2000]
[15000, 3000, 2000].

Comment: @cgmaster Honestly, that doesn't help me help you at all. I'm not sure what you mean by "extract index values from the function".

Answer (score 1):

With all your provided info, I check it on my own machine. 
The easiest way to convert a data.frame to a numpy array:

```
test = val.values
array = test[0]
```

You can always have access to column names

```
col = val.columns.values
```

Finally, match the names with values

```
link = list(zip(col, subsetsum(array,num)))
print(link)

# Output
[('A', 5000), ('B', 15000), ('C', 3000), ('D', 0), ('E', 2000)]
```

The `zip()` will match 2 arrays with the same length, and return a `zip object`. Then if you want to iterate and using print, first convert to `list()`. I hope this help!